# Most efficient way of continuously going through an array of nth length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I'm trying to go through an array with a fixed number of items and but the number of times I go through the array is unknown and can loop.

The result is supposed to be like red > blue > green > yellow > red > ...

What's the **most** efficient way to do this?

```
for (let i=0; i< nth; i++) {
    console.log(color(i));
};
```

```
function color(x){
    var colorArr = ['red','blue','green','yellow'];
    *** Code here ***
    return colorArr[i];
};
```

Comment: So do you want your result to be a series of console logs or a string result `"red > blue > green > yellow > red"`?

Comment: `colorArr[i];` I think the first option is what the OP want @NickParsons. Check [my anwser below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65965288/9071943) ^^!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the type of problem that [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) are great at solving. Generators are a standard way to let you get a (potentially infinite) series of elements, one at a time. While they're very elegant, they have a bit of a learning curve, so if haven't used them before and you just want to get the job done, [go with @Phong's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65965288/9071943).

```js
function* cycle(elements) {
  while (true) {
    yield* elements;
  }
}

// Example usage //

const COLORS = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

console.log('Use the generator in a loop');
for (const color of cycle(COLORS)) {
  console.log(color);
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) break;
}

console.log('Use the generator by itself');
const colorGenerator = cycle(COLORS);
console.log(colorGenerator.next().value);
console.log(colorGenerator.next().value);
console.log(colorGenerator.next().value);
console.log(colorGenerator.next().value);
console.log(colorGenerator.next().value);
```

Comment: @Denzyl Oh, I was surprised why the OP chose your answer. It seems too complex for using this as you said. Anyway, thanks for your comment **go with [Phong's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65965288/9071943)**

Comment: @Phong there's a reason generators exist, and this is one of their classic use cases - they're a very elegant solution for this kind of problem. I was simply just trying to say that for a newer programmer, first focus on learning what you need to to write a working program, later you can learn the features that make a program more readable. I don't know the O.P.'s skill level.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine the `"expected index"` in this way

```
const expectedIndex = i % colorArr.length;
```

It means that whenever the `i >= length_of_the_array`, then `"expected index"` will be restart.

**Debugging:**

- `nth = 6;`
- `colorArr.length = 4`
- *==>* So when `i = 0, 1, 2, 3` is fine.Then `i = 4, 5` the modular value is exactly expected index. *(More details you can see in the console log below)*

```js
var nth = 6;
for (let i = 0; i < nth; i++) {
    console.log(color(i));
};

function color(i){
    var colorArr = ['red','blue','green','yellow'];
    const expectedIndex = i % colorArr.length;
    // Remove the line below if you don't want to log debugging value
    console.log({i, length: colorArr.length, expectedIndex});
    return colorArr[expectedIndex];
};
```